# How do I add a custom URL to this box using Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

[image]
This website is using ACF to pull a product description and the link from POSTS.
When you click "Go to Product" it takes you to the product associated.

The owner wants to be able to place their own link, so the button goes to the link they've provided instead of the ID of the product post.

I've created this on ACF = this is where you select the product for the description. I've placed the product link option above it. [image]

**Here is the original code:**
`

```
                <?php if ($featured_product_enable): ?>
                    
                    <?php if (have_rows('featured_product')): ?>
                        <?php while (have_rows('featured_product')):
                            the_row();
                            // $blurb = get_sub_field( 'blurb' );
                            $product = get_sub_field('product');
                            $product_featured_excerpt = get_field('featured_excerpt', $product->ID);
                        ?>

                            <?php if ($product): ?>
                                <div class="feature-box <?php echo $feature_box_class; ?> margin-bottom-2">
                                    <h4>Featured Product</h4>
                                    <p><strong><?php echo $product->post_title; ?></strong><?php echo $product_featured_excerpt ? ' - ' . $product_featured_excerpt : '' ?></p>
                                    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink($product->ID); ?>" class="<?php echo $button_class; ?>">Go to Product</a></p>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

`

**Here is what I've added: **
`

```
                <?php if ($featured_product_enable): ?>
                    
                    <?php if (have_rows('featured_product')): ?>
                        <?php while (have_rows('featured_product')):
                            the_row();
                            // $blurb = get_sub_field( 'blurb' );
                            $product = get_sub_field('product');
                            $product_featured_excerpt = get_field('featured_excerpt', $product->ID);
                            $product_link = get_field('product_link');
                        ?>

                            <?php if ($product): ?>
                                <div class="feature-box <?php echo $feature_box_class; ?> margin-bottom-2">
                                    <h4>Featured Product</h4>
                                    <p><strong><?php echo $product->post_title; ?></strong><?php echo $product_featured_excerpt ? ' - ' . $product_featured_excerpt : '' ?></p>
                                    <p><a href="<?php echo esc_url($product_link); ?>" class="<?php echo $button_class; ?>">Go to Product</a></p>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

`

When I test my page, the button still takes me to the product page associated with the description rather than the URL I've selected.

Any advice?

```
                <?php if ($featured_product_enable): ?>
                    
                    <?php if (have_rows('featured_product')): ?>
                        <?php while (have_rows('featured_product')):
                            the_row();
                            // $blurb = get_sub_field( 'blurb' );
                            $product = get_sub_field('product');
                            $product_featured_excerpt = get_field('featured_excerpt', $product->ID);
                            $product_link = get_field('product_link');
                        ?>

                            <?php if ($product): ?>
                                <div class="feature-box <?php echo $feature_box_class; ?> margin-bottom-2">
                                    <h4>Featured Product</h4>
                                    <p><strong><?php echo $product->post_title; ?></strong><?php echo $product_featured_excerpt ? ' - ' . $product_featured_excerpt : '' ?></p>
                                    <p><a href="<?php echo esc_url($product_link); ?>" class="<?php echo $button_class; ?>">Go to Product</a></p>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

I was expecting the product description to populate as it does, but the button should be the URL I've selected.

Comment: Both those fields appear to be on the same "level", according to your screenshot. So why are you trying to use `get_sub_field` to get the value of one, and `get_field` for the other ...?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a post object in your project link so you have to extract the link from that object,
Try to add $product->id in your get_field function second parameter.

Use this Code below.

```
<?php if ($featured_product_enable): ?>
                    
    <?php if (have_rows('featured_product')): ?>
        <?php while (have_rows('featured_product')):
            the_row();
            // $blurb = get_sub_field( 'blurb' );
            $product = get_sub_field('product');
            $product_featured_excerpt = get_field('featured_excerpt', $product->ID);
            $product_ob = get_field('product_link', $product->ID);
        ?>

            <?php if ($product): ?>
                <div class="feature-box <?php echo $feature_box_class; ?> margin-bottom-2">
                    <h4>Featured Product</h4>
                    <p><strong><?php echo $product->post_title; ?></strong><?php echo $product_featured_excerpt ? ' - ' . $product_featured_excerpt : '' ?></p>
                    <p><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($product_ob->ID); ?>" class="<?php echo $button_class; ?>">Go to Product</a></p>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```